# Deploying Symfony2 on shared hosting

Tags: php, apache, symfony

I can not find reply to my question.
I am trying to understand how i should deploy symfony2 app on shared hosting.
I know i should rename my "web" catalog to "public_html", but i have many sites in this catalog.
My catalog's structure is like:

```
-public_html
  -www.firstsite.com
  -www.secondsite.com
  ...
  -www.nextsite.com
-private_html
```

So where i should put my files? app,src,vendor under public_html, and files from web i should put directly to "public_html"? Or catalog web should be in public_html and other files under public_html?
So i will have:

```
-public_html
  -...
  -web
-private_html
-app
-src
-...
```

EDIT:
Now i have whole app in "public_html/example/"
It's work fine, but it is safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a folder for your new website inside "public_html".
Let's say you have the domain "example.com".

You will have: public_html/example.com, public_html/example2.com, ..

Inside the folder example.com you will copy the folders: app, src, public.. (all Symfony's project main folders and files).

To answer to your question. "EDIT: Now i have whole app in "public_html/example/" It's work fine, but it is safe?". **Yes, it's safe.**

Just search on google for: "prevent directory traversal", if you want to make sure that it's secure.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution could be installing/deploying Symfony in a folder outside "public_html", let's name it "symfony_app".

Then, your directory structure could look something like this:

```
-public_html
  -www.firstsite.com
  -www.secondsite.com
  ...
-symfony_app
```

And then, you should make a symlink of a Symfony "web" folder in the "public_html" folder.

For example:

```
ln -s /home/your_username/symfony_app/web /home/your_username/public_html/www.symfony-site.com
```

** folder named "www.symfony-site.com" must not exist in "public_html" before creating symlink!

Last step would be adding new subdomain in cPanel. There you should connect your new subdomain with "www.symfony-site.com" symlink inside "public_html".

Comment: Can you make a symlink in a shared hosting? I am never see it if so how?

Comment: I was able to make a symlink on the Hostgator shared hosting and also on Avalon (Croatian company) shared hosting :)

Comment: yes, yes :)
you can find out more on http://matkodjipalo.com/index.php/2016/05/19/installing-symfony-on-hostgator-shared-hosting